# MYSQL - Count and GROUP from table1 and get info from table2

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling with a MySQL query which I cant get to work as I want.

In `table1` I have co_id, name, code, product, logindate.

in `table2` I have pr_id, productname, productno, price.

I want to count and group the PRODUCT from table1, so I can see how many that have picked for example product 1,2,3 etc.

But when I list the result on the page I will need productname, and productno for each id number in the GROUP search. table1.product is joined with table2.pr_id

This is what I have so far, but I think I am missing something with `INNER JOIN` or similar, right?

```
SELECT
  codes.pickedgift,
  products.productno,
  products.productname,
  COUNT(codes.pickedgift) as num
FROM
  codes,
  products
GROUP BY codes.pickedgift
ORDER BY codes.pickedgift
```

Comment: You need a join condition. (Also, use modern explicit `JOIN` syntax!)

Comment: Please don't talk about table1 and table2 when you have actual table names in your code. It makes things much less clear.

Answer (score 0):

you missing the join condition, when you join 2 tables you should link primary key in table1 to its foreign key in another table, so your query can be:

```
SELECT
  codes.pickedgift,
  products.productno,
  products.productname,
  COUNT(codes.pickedgift) as num
FROM
  codes INNER JOIN products ON codes.product = products.pr_id

GROUP BY codes.pickedgift
ORDER BY codes.pickedgift
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a sub-select for this query.

```
-- assuming I have your table structure correct.
SELECT p.productno, p.productname, num
FROM (SELECT codes.pickedgift, COUNT(codes.pickedgift) as num 
      FROM codes 
      GROUP BY codes.pickedgift) g
JOIN products p ON p.id = g.pickedgift
ORDER BY g.pickedgift
```

The other thing you have to make sure of is if you're using a group-by, the fields in your select must either be the fields in the group by, or aggregates.  MySQL let's you include columns that are not part of the group-by / aggregate, it becomes ambiguous as to which value `productno` and `productname` should be represented, which is why I opted for a sub-select instead.